# how to stop redirecting system.out away from console?

Tags: java, struts2, jboss

My java project uses struts 2 on jboss EAP 6.2 app server

`System.out.println` statements are redirected such that they dont show up on the console.

1. How can I track down where System.out is redirected to?

OR...

1. what settings can I check so that I know what to reset so that I can see console output?

EDIT:  I start the JVM by right clicking the server in the Eclipse servers tab and selecting "start"

Comment: how do you start the jvm process

Comment: Look at the server logs

Comment: Have you tried to see if your project's code is calling System.setOut anywhere?

Comment: server logs dont contain anything destined for System.out  ...and there is no System.setOut called.   So System.out has been mysteriously redirected somehow